# PHP inner join on id issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this script here

```
select distinct 
FirstName, 
LastName, 
table_2.status, 
'Shop' as receiver
from table_1
inner join table_2 on table_1.key_2 = table_2.'SHOP-'id
order by FirstName, LastName
```

the key_2 field has ids like SHOP-121 and the id in table 2 would just be the number 121.

How would I remove the SHOP- from key_2 or add SHOP- to id?

Comment: is your database already in use?<br>
There are more efficient solutions. Show us the tables involved and we can help you. *(planning to edit this answer later)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `CONCAT`

```
table_1.key_2 = CONCAT('SHOP-', table_2.id)
```

Remember that this will perform full table scan causing it to be slow on large database.